# How to test if method of imported class was called in component with jest/enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have such code in component:

```
export class VehiclesComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
    autoBind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
    const {
      query,
      filter,
      hasAccess,
      value2,
      value,
      value3,
      name,
      topics,
    } = this.props;
    const { data } = this.state;

    if (value || value2) {
      return DataService.getCars(
        filter,
        hasAccess,
        name,
        topics,
      ).then((cars) => {
        this.setState({
          data: [...data, ...cars],
        });
      });
    } else if (value3) {
      return DataService.getBuses(
        filter,
        hasAccess,
        query,
      ).then((buses) => {
        this.setState({
          data: [...data, ...buses],
        });
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return(...)
  }
};
```

My problem is that I do not know how to properly test which service was called depending on passed props(value, value2 or value3). I want to test if DataService.getBuses or DataService.getCars was called. I tried to mock that service:

```
import DataService from '../../services/DataService';
jest.mock("../../services/DataService");


DataService.mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      getCars: () => Promise.resolve([])
    }
  });
```

But my tests still fail, I have 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

```
  35 |
  36 |   componentDidMount() {
> 37 |     DataService.getCars().then(cars => {});
```

Comment: Looks like you auto-mocked `DataService` which means `getBuses` and `getCars` will be mock functions.  You can set the mock functions to return mock data and test them to see if they were called using the [Mock Functions API](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api).

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors how can I mock getBuses and getCars if they are inside DataService?

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors check my mocked func. I'm not sure if I did this correct as I still have an error

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by doing the following:

```
jest.doMock("../../services/DataService", () => ({
  getCars: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve([])),
}));
```